# JavaFX - Sequential Transition modify at runtime

Tags: java, animation, javafx, sequential

I have been exploring the Sequential Transition from JavaFX, and it seems a perfect fit for what I need. So, I am working on a JavaFX desktop application that essentially shows some pictures, text, and plays some video and audio files. Now, since some of those items are presented sequentially, I have decided to use the sequential transition. Now, I just run into a problem that I have tried to address but it does not seem to work as expected. Let's imagine that the sequence in which those items are presented is predefined in a Map. When those items are presented to the user, he/she needs to provide an answer, and if that is correct you can think that the item can be categorized as Done. However, in some of the cases I need that the user repeats some of the items for learning purposes. And that has to be done 'on-the-fly' since I have another window in which someone else decides which items must be repeated. As you can see, this requires some modification of the sequential transition at runtime. Is there any suggestions on how to address this challenge?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation for `SequentialTransition`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/SequentialTransition.html#getChildren()) states:

> It is not possible to change the children of a running SequentialTransition. If the children are changed for a running SequentialTransition, the animation has to be stopped and started again to pick up the new value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That explains why I was obtaining some rare behavior while running.

Now, is there any other way to address this issue?

Thanks!